# How to Mock Injected Dependencies

Tags: java, junit, guice, mockito

I'd like to use Guice in the following JUnit test class to inject mock dependencies, specifically the `resource`. How can I do this?

**Test**

```
public class SampleResourceTest extends ResourceTest {  

    @Override
    protected void setUpResources() throws Exception {
        // when(dao.getSample(eq("SIP"), eq("GA"))).thenReturn(sam);
        addResource(new SampleResource());
    }

    @Test
    public void getSampleTest() {
        Assert.assertEquals(sam, client().resource("/sample/SIP/GA").get(Sample.class));
    }

}
```

**Resource**

```
@Path("/sample")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SampleResource {   

    @Inject
    private SampleDao samDao;

    @GET
    @Path("/{sample}/{id}")
    public Sample getSample(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return samDao.fetch(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to inject the DAO into the unit test? Or are you already injecting the DAO into the class you are actually testing?

Comment: Sorry, I need to inject the `Resource` into the unit test, and mock the `DAO` within the injected `Resource`

Comment: Can you show code for the Resource? How is the DAO declared/used?

Comment: do you try @InjectMocks?

Comment: Ok, that helps, but one more question, then I think I'll have an answer for you. Where is your injector created/used?

Comment: @rmlan Currently, there is no injector. But I thought it should/would go in the body of the `SampleResourceTest` case.

Answer (score 12):

Consider overriding your Guice injection configuration using another test module.

I will show it using own example, but it's easy to adapt to your needs.

```
Module testModule = Modules.override(new ProductionModule())
    .with(new AbstractModule(){

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(QueueFactory.class).toInstance(spy(new QueueFactory()));
    }

});

Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(testModule);
QueueFactory qFactorySpy = injector.getInstance(QueueFactory.class);
```

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to bind the Mock DAO instance to the DAO class when creating your Guice injector. Then, when you add the `SampleResource`, use the getInstance method instead. Something like this:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(SampleDao.class).toInstance(mockDao);
        }
});

addResource(injector.getInstance(SampleResource.class);
```